# Spark 2.2 lambda expression

Tags: apache-spark, lambda

Below code is compatible with spark 1.3 but when i upgraded to spark 2.2 , it complains saying anonymous with lambda in java .

```
   JavaPairRDD<String, String> profile = profileRDD.leftOuterJoin(autoRDD).
            mapToPair(new PairFunction<Tuple2<String, Tuple2<String, Optional<String>>>, String, String>() {

                @Override
                public Tuple2<String, String> call(Tuple2<String, Tuple2<String, Optional<String>>> tuple)
                        throws Exception {
                    String filename = tuple._2()._1();
                    String stat = null;
                    if (tuple._2()._2().isPresent()) {
                        stat = tuple._2()._2().get();
                    }
                    return new Tuple2<String, String>(filename, stat);

                }
            });
```

Can anyone help to replace this code with lambda. Sorry I am not used to lambda. This is what I have tried :

```
    JavaPairRDD<String, String> profile = profileRDD.leftOuterJoin(autoRDD).
            mapToPair((Tuple2<String, Tuple2<String, Optional<String>>> tuple) -> {
                String filename = tuple._2()._1();
                String stat = null;
                if (tuple._2()._2().isPresent()) {
                    stat = tuple._2()._2().get();
                }
                return new Tuple2<String, String>(filename, stat);

            });
```

it complaints about return values now. Any help is appreciated .

Comment: java? why java?? :/

Answer (score 0):

Found solution:

```
 JavaPairRDD<String, String> profile = profileRDD.leftOuterJoin(autoRDD).
            mapToPair(tuple -> {
                String filename = tuple._2()._1();
                String stat = null;
                if (tuple._2()._2().isPresent()) {
                    stat = tuple._2()._2().get();
                }
                return new Tuple2<String, String>(filename, stat);

            });
```